# Automatically run Python scripts with QGIS closed

Tags: qgis, python, taskmanager

I have set up a Python script (.py) that runs manually in the QGIS interface (3.28.15).

Is it possible to call this script and run it automatically at predefined intervals (example 1 time per day with Windows 11 task scheduler)?

It is also okay with a call that opens the QGIS program and then runs it?